# Cassandra list<blob> read data incorrectly

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

Reading from list and got wrong data.

```
CREATE TABLE tt (k text PRIMARY KEY, msg list<blob>); 


static byte[] msg = new byte[] { 6, 6 };
static byte[] msg1 = new byte[] { 7, 7 };

    PreparedStatement upsert = session.prepare("update tt set msg = msg + ? where k = ?");
    session.execute(upsert.bind(Collections.singletonList(ByteBuffer.wrap(msg)), key));

    upsert = session.prepare("update tt set msg = msg + ? where k = ?");
    session.execute(upsert.bind(Collections.singletonList(ByteBuffer.wrap(msg1)), key));

    PreparedStatement statement = session.prepare("SELECT msg FROM tt where k = ?");
    ResultSet rs = session.execute(statement.bind(key));
    for (ByteBuffer bs : rs.one().getList("msg", ByteBuffer.class)) {
        for (byte b : bs.array())
            System.out.print(b + ", ");
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Data is stored correctly:

```
cqlsh:bellrock> select msg from tt;

 msg
------------------
 [0x0606, 0x0707]
```

But it outputs as:

0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 2, 7, 7, 
0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 2, 7, 7,

```
cqlsh:ks> show version
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.2.0 | CQL spec 3.3.0 | Native protocol v4]
```

Driver version: cassandra-driver-core 2.1.7.1

Answer (score 1):

it turned out to be a bug in driver cassandra-driver-core 2.1.7.1
it works fine after i put in earlier version 2.0.10.1